# What sites can I use to crowdsource my writing project?

Tags: creative-writing

I have a writing project I'd like to [crowdsource](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crowdsourcing). I imagine opening the project definition to an open call, and awarding the work to the most creative writer / thinker based on a sample of their work or on the complete deliverable.

What sites exist that provide a good platform for such a project?

Comment: Let me get this straight. You want to crowd-source your writing project, and also you want to crowd-source the crowd-sourcing?

Comment: I think he's looking for an existing platform that supports and facilitates the kind of project and participation he wants. That seems like a reasonable question.

Comment: I don't see how this is crowdsourcing. It appears that this is simply an attempt to get work done without having to pay a reasonable wage, like a logo design contest. Or do I misunderstand? This is spec work. Why on earth would you not simply find a good writer and hire him to write your project?

Comment: And there is nothing collaborative about choosing an individual from the crowd to do the final project. Without collaboration, this is not crowdsourcing.

Comment: He's perfectly correct in his usage of the term. Crowd-sourcing does not always imply collaborative work between multiple sources.  It can also mean an individual is sourcing solutions from a crowd of individuals: an individual proposes a project; X number of people submit their work to meet the requirements of the project to earn the prize. The individual then chooses the one they prefer. (CrowdSpring does this.) Absolutely no problem with his usage. The only question really is whether or not it has anything to do with writing.

Comment: My understanding is that there is a collaborative element to crowdsourcing. As much as I cringe at quoting Wikipedia, this expresses my understanding of crowdsourcing fairly well: Users—also known as the crowd—typically form into online communities, and the crowd submits solutions. The crowd also sorts through the solutions, finding the best ones.

Comment: If you carry on reading the Wikipedia article, it goes on to note: "The use of the term has spread to include models where discrete work is distributed to individuals within the crowd. Companies such as CloudCrowd and CrowdFlower do not use classic crowdSourcing because the crowd does not all participate together, or collectively sort through solutions."

Comment: Whether this is crowd sourcing or not, your need seems to be finding a good writer, who is available to write for you. Assuming that you are willing to pay for the work, you can find freelance writers at elance.com.

Comment: This is similar to what I would like... but with "vote it up" plugin.

Comment: I've been using this writer for my more demanding projects and would recommend him: dnswr772 AT gmail.com

Comment: Protected to avoid spamming/promotion.

Comment: Whatever site you decide to use, you might want to let people here know.  Lots of good writers.  Although, my impression is that most people here are working on their own stuff, not writing for hire.  Also, when it's all through, I'd be interested in an after-report: how satisfied you and the writer were, length of the writing, what you paid, success/failure of the end product, etc.

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at [Crowdspring](https://www.crowdspring.com). They have several categories for crowd-sourcing Writing Projects.

**Edit:** For more information on how the writing aspect works, see this blog post on their website: [Crowdsourced Writing Projects on crowdSPRING](http://blog.crowdspring.com/2010/02/crowdsourced-copywriting/)

**Note:** never used them myself, so can't comment on the actual service, quality etc.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [Contrich](http://www.contrich.com) for choosing the best writer that suits your project. You can copy a web page over there and ask potential writers to provide sample content on that page. Not only for selection purpose, you can execute your content project on Contrich and  track content progress on each web page.

Comment: Manish, as your profile list contrich.com as your website, per site rules you must disclose your affiliation with the site in your answer.

Comment: @justkt I am a member of [byteclip](http://www.byteclip.com) team and we built contrich for content writers to reduce communication gap and effectively collaborate content on a web page.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at some of the websites where you can crowdsource your writing projects:

1) http://www.crowdsourcing.org/navigate-search?q=writers

2) http://www.kickstarter.com/

Any one among these or all of them may help.

Thanks..

Comment: Also, these links can help you :3) http://minuteworkers.com/

4) http://www.innocentive.com/

5) www.odesk.com. Please let me know if you want more or if any of these is not useful to you.