# Is there anything like 99designs for text writing?

Tags: editing, technical-writing, marketing

I'm not a writer, but a technical oriented entrepreneur.. One of the barriers I always run into is that I'm also the lead guy for providing the content for marketing gigs, speaker bio's and website texts as I'm working in a specific niche market..

I know that what I write is correct, even well formulated English, but I'm certainly not very adept at writing good prose and attractive texts for readers..

I'm looking for a place where I can let others rewrite my texts into a higher quality result.

For my logo designs, and site designs I use sites like 99designs.com which are very attractive to me.. As a small-size entrepreneur I really like the concept, the adaptability and the diversity of the people there.

Is there somewhere similar on the web for my problem on rewriting texts?

Comment: The answer I gave to this question should help you: http://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/2832/what-sites-can-i-use-to-crowdsource-my-writing-project

Comment: @Craig - in fact I'd argue that this is a very close question (though not quite a duplicate, since the author is looking for editors).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Elance is not only for writing and editing, but almost any kind of remote work: http://www.elance.com.

Comment: Thanks.. A bit broader than I had intended, but might do the job..

Answer (score 2):

Check out http://www.scripted.com/

Comment: Can the OP get editors there was well as freelance writers?

Comment: This sounds great if editing is also available.. The site does not really make this clear..

Answer (score 2):

For top writers: http://wordfruit.com

I run Wordfruit -- if you have any questions, just let me know.

Comment: Are editors available on Wordfruit?  The OP has text and wants it polished.

Comment: Yes, we have editors.